# Catch FileNotFoundException in AsyncTask method

Tags: java, android, exception, android-asynctask

I'm getting the favicon of a website with a method. Of course not every website has a favicon. So I want to catch it. The app doesn't crash if the website doesn't have a favicon but I still get an FileNotFoundException in the LogCat.

The problem I'm encountering is that I can't catch it

When I add `catch (FileNotFoundException f)

to my try-catch block it tells me

```
Unreachable catch block for FileNotFoundException. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body.
```

The options I have is to remove it or to add a throws declaration to the doInBackground-method. The latter is not possible. This is the whole Try-Catch

```
try{
String baseURL      = getBaseURL ( sourceURLArr[i] );
System.out.println(baseURL + "/favicon.ico");
Bitmap favicon      = getBitmapFromURL( baseURL + "/favicon.ico");
Drawable fv         = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),     
Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(favicon, 20, 20, true));
source      [i].setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(fv, null, null, null);
} catch(NullPointerException e){

} catch(FileNotFoundException f){

}
```

I already tried to switch the FileNotFoundException with the NullPointerException but it was the same error. When I add the throws to the asynctask do in background method I get

`Exception FileNotFoundException is not compatible with throws clause in AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>.doInBackground(Void[])`

How can I now catch the FileNotFoundException?

Comment: you are not handling any file.. so why you are using FileNotFoundException ?

Comment: Well, my LogCat tells me that it is a FileNotFoundException. I'm downloading the favicon.ico - Or, I want to download it. And if it isn't available it is a FileNotFoundException since the File is not there and hasn't be found or am I understanding sth. wrong?

Comment: so better try it in the line Bitmap favicon      = getBitmapFromURL( baseURL + "/favicon.ico");

Comment: what is code for getBitmapFromURL function?

Answer (score 0):

getBitmapFromURL should handle filenotfoundexception internally and return null in that case.

I suppose you must be doing somewhere like this

url.openConnection().getInputStream();

surround that with IOException catch block. It will catch FileNotFoundException as well.
return null from that code piece

Comment: When I add it to the getBitmapFromURL method I also get the same error that its unreachable. Or should I add it as a throws decleration?

Answer (score 0):

If the code to generate bitmap from URL is something like,

```
    public Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String url)
    {
      URL url = new URL(sUrl);
      HttpURLConnection connection  = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
      InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
      Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
    }
```

then if I add, catch block for FileNotFoundException then it works.
Moreover, just try to add this line hope it works,

```
public Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String url) throws IOException
```

then your above code will work fine.
If your code is different then paste the code for it.

Comment: Rather posting the same answer again which is already posted. prefer voting it up or comment on that. Voting and Commenting on a answer is there for this purpose only.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this in the `AsyncTask`:

```
URL url = new URL("http://yourURL");
Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
```

And You could check if img is null and if it is then image is not found and you can do something (or nothing). In your case I think that you should maybe put that `try catch` block in `getBitmapFromURL()` function also because I suppose exception occurs in that function and it's not propagated to `AsyncTask`.
Posting `getBitmapFromURL()` code would clarify things better.